Which version of Psalm 80:19 is closest in intent to the original?
We read in Psalm 80:19 ( KJV):

Turn us again, O Lord God of hosts, cause thy face to shine; and we shall be saved.

Some other versions have a slightly different wording, to include ' to shine on us ' For instance, we have in NASB :

Lord God of armies, restore us;
Make Your face shine upon us, and we will be saved.

My question is : which version of Psalm 80:19 is closest in intent to the original ?

A very literal translation of Ps 80:19 would be:

YHWH God of hosts/armies, Restore [us], Shine Your face and we are
saved

We observe the following:

"upon us" is not explicitly in the text but is strongly implied
The verb הֲשִׁיבֵ֑נוּ could be translated as either "turn", "restore", "return", etc.

Thus, both the KJV and the NASB give a good translation of the Hebrew.

My edition of NASB does not say "Lord of armies," but "awaken your power, God. " But either way, I think NASB is better because it captures the psalmist's sense of remorse over the military defeat of his nation, which is northern Israel, not Judah. The KVJ's "turn us" is less clear about this than the NASB's "restore us." Note the references  to the northern tribes from my version of NASB, which also appear in KJV:

Listen, Shepherd of Israel, Who leads Joseph like a flock; You who are
enthroned above the cherubim, shine forth! Before Ephraim, Benjamin,
and Manasseh, awaken Your power, And come to save us! 3 God, restore
us And make Your face shine upon us, and we will be saved.

For several years I have been deeply moved by this psalm because of its expression of repentance by a psalmist of the North, who apparently feels a deep sense of loss because of his country's defeat (possibly its destruction as a political entity by Assyria). He himself remains faithful to Yahweh and expresses the hopes of his countrymen for restoration/salvation, centering on the Temple of Jerusalem (thus the reference to God's throne between the cherubim).
Conclusion: NASB is preferred because it expresses the psalmist's feeling of military defeat and thus makes it clear that he and his northern countrymen seek both spiritual and political restoration/salvation.
